# How to yank word from all selected lines in visual mode?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

In the middle of a line, Press `v` and select multiple lines.
How to yank the word at current cursor from all selected lines and add spaces if the word is shorter than the longest one to make copied columns aligned.
For example, current cursor is in the beginning of second data_out from first line.
Please note below example is in the middle of a file.

```
     ...
     data_out => data_out,
     read     => read,
     write    => write,
     full     => full,
     notempty => notempty,
     ...
```

After "copy" I can paste below columns.

`data_in ,`
`data_out,`
`read    ,`
`write   ,`
`full    ,`
`notempty,`

Comment: Do you really mean `yank`? Or do you just want to edit the text?

Comment: @Rich Seems hard to demonstrate tailing spaces, so I add a ','.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with using block selection ([`:help 04.4`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_04.txt.html#04%2e4)) and `A` ([`:help v_b_A_example`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#v_b_A_example)):

- `<c-q>Gx`: use visual block to delete leading space
- `f <c-q>G$x`: delete the block from the space to the end of line
- `<c-q>G$A,<esc>`: add the comma to the end of each line

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> above is intended to start block selection -- as it was noted in the comments, the default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>; I'm using the alternative mentioned in [`:help CTRL-Q`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui_w32.txt.html#CTRL%2dQ).

You could also do it through substitute([`:help :su`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3asu)):

- `%s/^\s*//`
- `%s/\s=.*$/,/`

---

**Edit:**

> I want it works in visual mode because sometimes the code is not
>   perfectly column aligned. So hope there is an easy way to column copy
>   in the visual mode instead of manually align the code first.

You can do this without changing the code visually; what you really want is to retrieve the number of the lines currently selected:

```
function! MyIndent()
    silent s/^\s*//
    silent s/\s=.*$/,/
endfunction

vnoremap <leader>i :call MyIndent()<CR>
```

With this you can select the lines and hit leader (usually <kbd>\</kbd>)+<kbd>i</kbd> to perform the changes.

Comment: visual block is normally `<c-v>` but sometimes `<c-q>` on windows

Comment: @Mass nice catch; I've updated the answer.

Comment: I want to find a way in visual mode not visual block mode.  Gx is selecting all lines. The example I show is a very simple case, it's inside a huge text file.

Comment: @Fisher Why does it have to be visual mode? That's an odd and pretty arbitrary restriction. As for `Gx` selecting all lines, just use an appropriate movement command that works in your file (which you haven't shown us) instead of `G`.

Comment: The first line seems to delete the first character of each word, too. Are you missing an `h`?

Comment: And the second regexp doesn't place commas in the right place. How about this instead? `%s/ =.*/,`

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that whilst you produce the correct result for the sample given, you're performing different edits than the OP was expecting? (i.e. you're operating on first word in line rather than second) I couldn't figure out how your answer was supposed to work until I tried it, because I was trying to figure out how your commands could possibly operate on the parts of the lines after the `=>`.

Comment: @Rich both the commands and substitute work fine here (not missing `h` or misplaced commas) -- maybe there is some difference in our configuration. Indeed I missed that it is supposed to work with the second word -- the example should have made that clear. In any case, the purpose of my answer was to give an example and give pointers to the documentation, as *the OP didn't give any hint of what he has tried, where he was struggling*.

Comment: Aha! I can get the first command to work if I change `'selection'` from the default to `exclusive`. Do you perhaps have that set in your config? (I'm testing in `vim -Nu NONE`). However, I can't figure out any way the second regular expression could leave whitespace between the words and the commas. As for the change of technique, I understood the purpose of your answer: that's why I already upvoted it!

Comment: @Rich I want it works in visual mode because sometimes the code is not perfectly column aligned. So hope there is an easy way to column copy in the visual mode instead of manually align the code first.

Comment: @Rich indeed, I'm using `behave mswin`, which does change `'selection'`. And actually I had misread your message -- my approach misses the spaces before the comma. I'm going to update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've removed the requirement of copy un-aligned columns. Don't want to things too complicated. Which makes visual block mode is acceptable.

Comment: Now I have an idea: yank the selected lines with Y then :tabe and paste copied lines. After this we can do the remaining work, manipulating the text, copy, close the temporary buffer, paste the result to original file. Thank you all!

Comment: Seems recorded macro is not working after the :tabe. '<,'> should be used to control the working range.